# How to concatenate / combine series of columns in R?

Tags: r, concatenation, series

I have two column series - A series and B series.

```
df <- data.frame(A_1_1 =  'a',
                 A_2_1 =  'b',
                 A_3_1 =  'c',
                 B_0_1 =  'x',
                 B_0_2 =  'y',
                 B_0_3 =  'z'
)
```

I need to concatenate the A series with B series in the same sequence, to get the desired output.

[image]

Attempting something to this effect:

```
df %>% str_c(starts_with("A_"),"-",starts_with("B_"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide an example data frame, you can use `dput`

Comment: Try this example: `mapply(paste, mtcars[, c(1,2)], mtcars[, c(3,4)])`

Answer (score 0):

This one did the job

```
df %>% {map2_dfc(select(.,starts_with("A_")),
                 select(.,starts_with("B_")),
                       function(x,y){
                         str_c(x,"-",y)
                       })} %>% View()
```